# User input from scanner results in an infinite loop in try/catch block even when using NextLine in Catch

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

If a correct filename is entered, there's no issue. If an incorrect filename is entered, the infinite loop keeps telling the user to enter a file name. But it doesn't wait on the user to enter the filename. It keeps processing the first erroneous data in an infinite loop. **I am using nextLine in the catch block** which is supposed to clear the erroneous input. Also tried reset(). What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static String reader() {
    boolean fileCorrect = false;

    // Holds the data from the file and is returned.
    StringBuilder fromFile=new StringBuilder("");

    // Loop until the user enter's a filename that the system can find.
    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nEnter filename to open: ");

        //Try with resources to open Scanner object for keyboard input
        try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            String fileName = keyboard.next();

            // Trim leading/trailing spaces from filename
            fileName = fileName.trim();

            // The file object opened with try below
            File iFile = new File(fileName);

            //Attempt to open the file, which is automatically closed by try with resources.
            try (Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(iFile))
            {
                //Read the file and append data to the string.
                while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
                {
                    fromFile = fromFile.append(fileInput.nextLine());
                }

                //If we make it this far, no need to loop.
                fileCorrect = true;
            }

            // Catch specific first, a child of IOException. Most likely to happen.
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage() + ": File not found");
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                keyboard.nextLine();
             }

            // If the scanner somehow closed before data was read.
            catch (IllegalStateException ex)
            {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage() + ": Error reading from file");
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }

            // Something else went wrong. Generic catch-all to keep the program from crashing.
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle these
        }
    }
    while (!fileCorrect);
```

Comment: What it's supposed to do when you enter an incorrect filename ?

Comment: Also do not silently swallow exceptions `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle these
        }`

Comment: If you have `try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in))` - will it not automatically call close on the `System.in` Scanner?

Comment: Can you accept an answer please? If none are suitable, leave some feedback so we know what to fix/improve. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` to before the do-while loop

If you have it as `try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in))` - it will automatically call close on the `System.in Scanner` and `next` will not work

If you had a proper Exception handler

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
      ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

you would see the message

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if else statements in your program with break keyword. If your input is the incorrect file name use break keyword so it would not continue the infinite block.

e.g

```
for() 
{
if(filename==false)
{
break;
}
else
{
// continue your logic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the first `try` block. Change it from this:

```
try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
```

to this:

```
try {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The first will keep trying to read text and failing and trying again, etc. because the `Scanner` is closed, and the text can't be read as @ScaryWombat said in his comment